# Disabling IE Security popup with Registry entry

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

For an unattended installation, how could I disable the popup in IE8:
*When you send information to the internet it might be possible for others to see that information?*

This popup blocks my scripts.

I have already tried this, with no avail:

```
Registry Poke
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3
Key : 1601 Type :REG_DWORD Value : 0
```

Answer (score 4):

When you set it in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive, the setting will only apply in the current user's context (eg. Trusted Installer).

Set it for the entire machine, by setting the corresponding key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3]
"1601"=dword:00000000
```

To force all users to read Internet Security Settings from the HKLM hive, set:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"Security_HKLM_only"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution also works for IE10 on Windows 7.